# Pass parameters from form submission to specified route in Syfmony2

Tags: symfony

I have a route in my routing.yml which is as follows:

```
pattern:  /admin/clients/{clientid}/projects/{projectid}/review/{id}/comments
defaults: { _controller: ShoutAdminBundle:Project:revcomm }
requirements:
    _method:  POST
```

Now, on a page (the comments page) I have a form where the user will enter a comment and then submit it to that page. Then the user clicks submit, they will be brought back to the same page but their comment will have been submitted to the database and then displayed.

My Form code looks like this:

```
        <form action="{{ path('ShoutAdminBundle_adminprojectreviewcommentssuccess') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} class="blogger">
            {{ form_errors(form) }}

            <p class="comments">
                {{ form_label(form.from, 'Your Name*', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.from) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.from, { 'attr': {'class': 'textfield'}}) }}
            </p>
            <p class="comments">
                {{ form_label(form.comment, 'Your Comment*', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.comment) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.comment, { 'attr': {'class': 'textfield'}}) }}
            </p>
            <p class="comments_save">
                <input type="submit" value="Post Your Comment" id="savebutton" class="savebutton" />
            </p>
            {{ form_rest(form) }} 
        </form>
```

Now. When the page is rendered I get the following error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The
>   "ShoutAdminBundle_route" route has some missing mandatory parameters
>   ("id", "projectid").") in
>   "ShoutAdminBundle:Default:projectreviewcomments.html.twig" at line 54.

How do I pass the variables `{clientid}`, `{projectid}` and `{id}` to the page? These variable are declared in the page already, it's a question of how do I include them in the form submission?

Cheers

Comment: +1 for finally helping me figure out, how to add classes to form elements!

Comment: I think we've both highlighted the fact that the documentation for Symnfony is very, very patchy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass them via your controller by using an associative array:

```php
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    public function revcommAction($clientid, $projectid, $id)
    {
        // ...

        $params = array(
            'clientid'  => $clientid,
            'projectid' => $projectid,
            'id'        => $id
        );
        return $this->render('ShoutAdminBundle:Default:projectreviewcomments.html.twig', $params);
    }
}
```

To render a link (or a path for the form action) to this controller in a template, you can use `path()` for relative and `url()` for absolute links. The second argument takes in any arguments required to construct the link, for example:

```
<a href="{{ path('my_route_name', {'clientid': clientid, ...}) }}"></a>
```

Comment: I've tried that but had to make a change. Where you use => I replaced them with : otherwise an error was generated. Also, the URL that is now generated includes ?clientid=1 at the end of the URL?

Comment: @mickburkejnr Sorry for the '=>' typo. Every parameter that is not required for the route will be passed as a GET variable. You must only pass the values, which the router needs for constructing the link. I assumed you were using the same route pattern ('pattern:  /admin/clients/{clientid}/projects/{projectid}/review/{id}/comments')

Comment: Ok I got it to work. I you have to write {'clientid' :clientid} in the form submission and then it works like a charm! Many thanks :)